# How to register {my namespace]\Site\Service\Category?

Tags: development, joomla-4.x, custom-component, category

My component is using Joomla Categories and I'm using the following code to fetch a category:

```
$component = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_khub');
$category = $component->getCategory(['published' => 0])->get($catid);
```

Joomla is complaining that class `Khub\Component\Khub\Site\Service\Category` does not exists (at JROOT/libraries/src/Categories/CategoryFactory.php:65).

Of course this works OK with "com_content" and "com_banners" and I've tried to understand where and how those components register `Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Service\Category` and `Joomla\Component\Banners\Site\Service\Category` respectively, but with no success (JPATH_COMPONENT/services/provider.php contents are pretty much similar to what I have for my own component),

What am I missing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me. I was looking at the /services/provider.php file on the administrator part.

This problem was on the site part.

I simply copied "Category.php" from JROOT/components/com_content/src/Service and made the necessary adjustments.